# Why do I see IIS start page for certain URLs?

Tags: firefox, proxy

When I enter URL for certain sites in Firefox address bar and hit enter I am shown IIS start page. There is nothing wrong with the website, but I wonder why this page is shown. It is noteworthy that I used to use a VPN service that connected using a dedicated application and once connected, my system was tunneled completely, so all my applications used the VPN connection automatically. I thought this might have tampered with system proxy settings or something.
[image]

Also, I am having problem only with opening the homepage like www.example.com, but when I append another part of the URL heading to a certain page, the page opens normally.